# ReferenceError: share_prompt is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, facebook, undefined

Hi I try to do share on facebook my post. But it show Reference Error Share_Prompt() not defined. 
Here is My code for facebook share. 
error :  Uncaught ReferenceError: share_prompt is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

```
 <a class="btn-style-1 style-big" onclick="share_prompt()" style="background-color: #3b5998;float: right;">Share on Facebook</a>

<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src =     "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=xxx";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}  (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId: 'xxx', 
status: true, 
cookie: true,
xfbml: true,
version: 'v2.8'
});

};
 function share_prompt()
{
     FB.ui(
 {
                             method: 'feed',
                             name: '<?php echo $job_title ?>',
                             link: 'http://fbfunzone.com/jobPortalplus/jobsdetail.php?id=<?php echo $jid ?>',

                             picture: 'http://xyza.com/xxxx/images/blog/blog-detail-img.jpg',
                             caption: 'www.xxx.com',
                             description: '<?php echo $head_line ?>',
                             author : 'xxx',
                             display: 'iframe',
                             message: ''

                           },
                           function(response) {
                             if (response && response.post_id) {

                             } else {
                              // alert('Post was not published.');
                             }
                           }
                );

                }

</script>
```

Comment: Some time its working fine  or some time did not work.

Comment: Put the script before the HTML element. (Or use proper contemporary event handling methods to begin with.)

Comment: i already put my code before html